# How to highlight search tool matches in minibuffer?

Tags: spacemacs, search, minibuffer, ivy

These search tools list results in the minibuffer, but the matches are not highlighting:

- SPC s a f (ag)
- SPC s g f (grep)
- SPC s k f (ack)
- SPC s t f (pt)

[image]

Help describe does highlight matches.  Would be nice if ag/grep/ack/pt did the same.

Is there a way to highlight matches for ag/grep/ack/pt?
Does your Ivy search-tool highlight matches?

Other than that, I am really enjoying how tightly the search tool is integrated into the editor.

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

**Update_1**

I restarted Spacemacs with the default .spacemacs file and there is no highlighting in the search results.
I guess it's a Spacemacs bug.

The following is a listing of what I did:

```
Renamed .spacemacs to .spacemaces_backup
Restarted emacs, and answer the questions:
    What is your preferred editing style? vim
    What distribution of spacemacs would you like to start with? spacemacs
    What type of completion framework do you want? ivy
(this generates a new .spacemacs file)

Restarted emacs, 
    SPC s k f
    ack from ... : test
"test" is in the search results, but not highlighted.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it looks like for me:
[image: counsel-ack.png]

Try to load just counsel.el with `emacs -Q`: you should see the same colored output.
After that, you need to figure out which part of your config makes the colors disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the response abo-abo.
I finally got around to trouble shooting this.
Please refer to **Update_1** in the question.